# how to get current index repeater using angular

Tags: angular

I am working on angular project , In this code  below is for animation satellite meteorological images .

```
 TOTAL = 20; // total number of images
  currentIndex = 1;

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  play() {

    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(this.currentIndex)

      if (this.currentIndex + 1 > this.TOTAL) this.currentIndex = 1;
      else this.currentIndex++
    }, 400)

  }

  stop() {


  }
```

html

```
<img src="/gulf_ksa1/{{currentIndex}}.jpg" name="animation" style="width:auto;" class="img-responsive">

<ion-button size="large" (click)="play()">تشغيل</ion-button>
<ion-button size="large" (click)="stop()">ايقاف</ion-button>
```

My code above is working fine with animating images , but what l want to do When user click on function stop , i want to get current Index even stop animating .

any idea please ?

Comment: you can use iterator pattern for that

https://github.com/torokmark/design_patterns_in_typescript/tree/master/iterator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the code to following,

```
TOTAL = 20; // total number of images
currentIndex = 1;
timeID = null;
clearIntv;

   constructor() {

   }

   ngOnInit() {

   }

   play() {

    this.clearIntv = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(this.currentIndex)

      if (this.currentIndex + 1 > this.TOTAL) this.currentIndex = 1;
      else this.currentIndex++
    }, 400)

   }

   stop() {
    console.log(this.currentIndex);  // Get Current Index
    clearInterval(this.clearIntv); // Stop animation

   }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering . i got error on click on fun `stop` `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'clearInterval' of undefined`

Comment: I have question . How can i add lazy loading while satellite images load ? l mean l want show loading image gif if satellite images are still under loading !

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **clearInterval** to stop the timer and then you can get your current index

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
TOTAL = 20; // total number of images
currentIndex = 1;

private interval;

constructor() {

}

ngOnInit() {

}

play() {

  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(this.currentIndex)

    if (this.currentIndex + 1 > this.TOTAL) this.currentIndex = 1;
    else this.currentIndex++
  }, 400)

}

stop() {
  if (this.interval) {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    console.log(this.currentIndex);
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: I have question . How can i add lazy loading while satellite images load ? l mean l want show loading image gif if satellite images are still under loading !

Comment: I created a snippet for you - https://jsfiddle.net/fycwbns8/19/.

Alternatively you can create an element with absolute positioning and hide this element on img 'onload' event